# How do I prevent my enemy from sometimes stopping when hitting a wall? Probably caused by clipping and bumping into corners

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I prevent my enemy from occasionally stopping when hitting a wall?

I believe the problem is that they are clipping into the wall and are then unable to move.
Another problem may be that when they hit a corner, they go in the direction that hits the corner and again clips in the wall.

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    currentDirection = Vector2.right;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = currentDirection * moveSpeed;
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        currentDirection = GetRandomDirection();
    }
}

Vector2 previousDirection;

Vector2 GetRandomDirection()
{
    Vector2[] directions = { Vector2.up, Vector2.right, Vector2.down, Vector2.left };

    Vector2[] availableDirections = new Vector2[directions.Length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (directions[i] != previousDirection)
        {
            availableDirections[index] = directions[i];
            index++;
        }
    }

    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, availableDirections.Length);

    Vector2 randomDirection = availableDirections[randomIndex];

    previousDirection = randomDirection;

    return randomDirection;
}
```

I tried to use some code that moves the enemy backwards a bit when hitting a wall but it still didn't work.

Comment: Doesn't this loop while the enemy is clipped with the wall continuously changing the direction to a new random direction? If that's the case, it would make sense that it appears to not really move.  It may require manually setting the location of the object away from colliding for it to behave normally again.

Comment: Could you provide more context on how the enemy moves, the intended behaviour, and how the obstacle looks? Maybe paste a sketch with your question?

Comment: The enemy moves in a linear line until it hits a wall, when it will then either move up, down, left, or right but it shouldn't move in the same direction twice. The obstacle in this case is just a vertical wall with a collider attached, when it sometimes moves up or down then there is a horizontal wall to hopefully get the enemy to bounce off of in another direction. Most of the time however, the enemy is stuck in the corner after hitting the wall and is unable to move. I hope I could try to add more context if needed

Comment: Use a List<Vector2> for available directions.  It is possible for you to have a Vector2.zero in the available directions since the length of available directions is equal to the length of  directions.  This is likely the reason.